How to Check if a ScriptableObject is Null or Contains Data in Unity Visual Scripting?
In Unity Visual Scripting, I'd like to check to check if a Scriptable Object has data in it or not. So to do that, I tried using a Null Check node on the data directly:

You can clearly see that there's a Scriptable Object in there, but the Null Check is triggering the Null branch.
I then cast the Scriptable Object into a variable before I ran the Null Check, to make sure that wasn't the issue:

That still seemed to trigger the wrong branch.  So I added a "Wait Until Next Frame" node, but got the same result.
I then wrote a subgraph called "Null Check Using Equality" which passed in an Object input and used an Equal node to check it against null.  
Again, the wrong branch was triggered.
I think I must be misunderstanding something fundamental here.  Any ideas on what it could be?

A followup note: I ended up adding an enum to my Scriptable Object to specify whether or not one of the variables had a Scriptable Object assigned to it or not.  So then I can just check the enum instead of directly referencing the variable and checking if it's null or not. A kludge and unrelable, but I couldn't figure out a way to solve this issue!
